# Odd row behavior with bootstrap - Help me correct it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem where my DIV elements are not being wrapped properly using Bootstrap. I have it set up to just create the elements and then let bootstrap handled the rows for me This is the result I get...

Sorry for the blurry image, I dont know if my company wants me to share the data in the blocks

[image: Blurred image of grid issue]

As you can see, it acts as though there is a push/pull in that one element making it skip 3 spots. NOTE: This spot changes when the window changes sizes, so there could be multiple gaps or just a big one like this.

I think it has something to do with the height of the boxes but I am not sure. If i set a hard coded height (such as 20em;) then it seems to work fine. However, I don't want to set a height because the content changes constantly in the finished product. Maybe someone knows a CSS trick. I have tried most of the "clearfix" solutions out there but have had no luck.

Parent code (Some code removed to save space):

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var machine in Model)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_MachineCard", machine)
    }
</div>
```

Partial Code (Some code removed to save space):

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="display: block">
@if (onlineStatus)
{
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
            @switch (@Model.DTCodeName)
            {
                case "Unknown DTC":
                    <span class="label label-danger pull-right">@Model.DTCodeName</span>
                    break;
                case "Production":
                    <span class="label label-primary pull-right">@Model.DTCodeName</span>
                    break;
                case "Bin Change":
                    <span class="label label-info pull-right">@Model.DTCodeName</span>
                    break;
                default:
                    <span class="label label-warning pull-right">@Model.DTCodeName</span>
                    break;
            }
            <h5>@Model.MachineName</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <h3 class="no-margins">@Model.JobName</h3>
            <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
                @partCountPercentage% <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
                <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
                    <span class="sr-only">@partCountPercentage% Complete</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>@Model.PartCount / @Model.PartLimit</div>
            <div>DT Code: @Model.DTCodeName</div>
            <span><small>Cycles Per Min: @Math.Round((double)Model.RunCyclesPerProdHour / 60, 3)</small></span>
            <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion: @txtTimeLeft</small></span>
        </div>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
            <span class="label pull-right">Offline</span>
            <h5>@Model.MachineName</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
            <h3 class="no-margins">Machine is offline</h3>
            <div>Last Active: @Model.MachineOnlineTime.Value.DateTime</div>
            <div>DT Code: @Model.DTCodeName</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Removed a screenshot

FIX:
Added .box class to the top div for where the column size classes are (col-xx-x). Thanks to vanburen for the fix.

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .box:nth-child(4n+1) { clear: left; } } @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) { .box:nth-child(3n+1) { clear: left; } } @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { .box:nth-child(2n+1) { clear: left; } }
```

Comment: Check if any of your div styles have a `float: right` in them.

Comment: That's a float problem , not bootstrap

Comment: This happens when use floats to layouts. Bootstrap still uses it

Comment: The floats are inside the DIV though and not an attribute of the div box. Why would that cause this problem? I can change the height of each DIV to a static height and it works perfect.

Comment: Please provided generated HTML and not your templates **and** the relevant CSS. As others have noted, this looks like a float issue. When there isn't enough room for a floated DIV it drops below the previous one and attempts to make it's way all the way to the left side, but it ends up snagging on a DIV that doesn't allow it to move all the way to the left. From your image it looks like it clears one box but snags the other as it's slightly taller. Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/svfb182p/1/) demonstrating the issue. Notice Box 4 _"snags"_ on box 2 when you re-size the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @hungerstar, I already knew it was something like this but how do I fix this issue? I have tried the "clearfix" bootstrap tricks that people have recommended on the internet but I have been unable to get that to work.

Comment: @BinaryNexus as requested before, please provide generated HTML **and** relevant CSS. _Note:_ a clearfix won't help you here. A clearfix is meant to prevent parent elements from collapsing when child elements are floated. If you have a DIV that contains DIVs that are floated but want the outer DIV to have a boarder that wraps the inner DIVs, you'd use a clearfix. Floated elements don't take up space so the parent element effectively has no height (as the children don't take up space) and the border on the parent DIV won't wrap the inner DIVs as intended. `min-height` might be your friend here.

Comment: @hungerstar Added a screenshot of the IE tools with the problem div expanded. I would add the css files but there are several. min-height wouldnt work here based on the problem you described if I understood it correctly.

Comment: `min-height`, `height` and `max-height` could all work here. It depends on your content and how you want to display/handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on the code you provided. Since you're using multiple column breakpoints (`col-md-3` and `col-sm-6`) you'll have to clear the float for the number of columns attributed at the corresponding breakpoint:

**col-md-3 = 4 columns @ min-width: 992px**

**col-sm-6 = 2 columns @ max-width: 991px**

See working Example Snippet at FullPage and reduce the viewport.

```css
/**FOR DEMO ONLY**/

body {
  padding-top: 25px;
}
.ibox {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20), 0 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
/**END DEMO CSS**/

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .box:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .box:nth-child(2n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 1</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 2</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 3</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 4</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName JobName JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 5</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 6</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 7</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 8</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName JobName JobName JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 box">
      <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
        <div class="ibox-title">
          <span class="label label-danger pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-primary pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-info pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <span class="label label-warning pull-right">DTCodeName</span>
          <h5>MachineName 9</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="ibox-content">
          <h3 class="no-margins">JobName</h3>
          <div class="stat-percent font-bold text-success">
            partCountPercentage <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="progress" style="margin-bottom: 0.5em; margin-top: 0.5em;">
            <div style="width: @partCountPercentage%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="@partCountPercentage" role="progressbar" class="progress-bar progress-bar-success">
              <span class="sr-only">partCountPercentage Complete</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>PartLimit</div>
          <div>DT Code</div>
          <span><small>Cycles Per Min:</small></span>
          <span class="pull-right" title="Based on current Cycle Time"><small>Est. Completion</small></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually loathe to suggest a plugin for problems like this, but there's really no good cross-browser compatible way to arrange variable-height cards in columns like you want to. [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is the most common solution for this - I'd look into it. It's pretty simple to use:

```
$('.row').masonry({
  // options
  itemSelector: '.card',
  columnWidth: 200
});
```