# bootstrap columns skip a line on col-xs-6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, newline

I have a bootstrap grid with four items. My problem is that the item in position 3 jumps to a new line and doesn't show in a grid layout.

[This is a screen shot of what is produced with the following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoGQq.png)

```
<!-- Position One -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="stock-grid-item">
            <a href="item1.html">
                <img src="/images/image1.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="stock-grid-details">
            <p class="name"><a href="item1.html">Item One Title</a></p>
            <p class="price">$10.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Position Two -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="stock-grid-item">
            <a href="item2.html">
                <img src="/images/image2.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="stock-grid-details">
            <p class="name"><a href="item2.html">Item Two Title</a></p>
            <p class="price">$10.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Position Three -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="stock-grid-item">
            <a href="item3.html">
                <img src="/images/image3.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="stock-grid-details">
            <p class="name"><a href="item3.html">Item Three Title</a></p>
            <p class="price">$10.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Position Four -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="stock-grid-item">
            <a href="item4.html">
                <img src="/images/image4.jpg" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="stock-grid-details">
            <p class="name"><a href="item4.html">Item Two Title</a></p>
            <p class="price">$10.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Odd row behavior with bootstrap - Help me correct it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35342540/odd-row-behavior-with-bootstrap-help-me-correct-it)

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your code inside this.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        // your codes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Also I made some adjustments to your code to remove improper uses of tags.

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/exbf1qsm/2/)